# error when executing insert with nodejs + sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following function to insert a record in a MySQL database. I am using NodeJS and Sequelize.

```
await WeatherData.create ({
control_esp_id: req.body.control_esp_id,
variable_id: req.body.variable_id,
read_date: req.body.date,
value: req.body.value
})
.then ((weatherdata) => {
return res.status (200) .json ({
error: false,
message: "Data regarding the Line / Bay / Room successfully registered!",
weatherdata
});
})
.catch ((err) => {
console.log (err);
return res.status (400) .json ({
error: true,
code: 203,
message: err
});
})
```

However, the following error message is occurring when I execute the function. i have other inserts and they are working perfectly. Only from this type of model that the error is occurring to me:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at WeatherData._initValues (backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:140:49)
at new Model (backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:118:10)
at new WeatherData (backend/src/app/models/WeatherData.js:9:1)
at Function.build (backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2157:12)
at Function.create (backend/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:2207:23)
at store (backend/src/app/controllers/WeatherDataController.js:62:31)

```
class WeatherData extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        super.init({
            read_date: DataTypes.DATE,
            value: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        }, {
            sequelize,
        });
        return this;
    }

    
    static associate(models) {
        this.belongsTo(models.ControlEsp, {
            foreignKey: 'control_esp_id',
            as: 'control_esp',
        });
        this.belongsTo(models.Variable, {
            foreignKey: 'variable_id',
            as: 'variable',
        });
    }
}

sequelizePaginate.paginate(WeatherData);

export default WeatherData
```

Regards

Comment: Please provide the full error, including which file the error references, and ideally the contents of that file.

Comment: update questions